Why Tablix Record More Than One Makes Body Background Image make 2 Pages in RDLC With VB.NET
I'm Trying use background image in body report but if
Tablix record more than one makes body Background Image make 2 Pages in RDLC With VB.NET.
Is there something wrong or is there something I should set?
Please guide me
thanks
Code in form1
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim form2 = New Form2()
        Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.DataGridView1.DataSource)
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WindowsApplication1.Report1.rdlc"
        form2.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

Code Object class model
Public Class Product
    Public Property Productname() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Double
End Class

Code in form2
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class

Result in page1 reportviewer

Result in page2 reportviewer

Result in datagridview

Background Image in Body

